# click event fired even if the button has not been clicked

Tags: jquery

I want bind a function to a button using jquery. But the event is fired when the page is load instead of when the button is clicked. this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function getStudents(view) {

    /* do something */
    }
    $('#buttonAB').click(getStudents("corsoAB"));

});
```

what I'm wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your function inside another function:

```
$('#buttonAB').click(function() {
    getStudents("corsoAB");
});
```

Your current code is executing your `getStudents` function on page load, and assigning the returned value of the function to the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

With parameter means

```
 $('#buttonAB').click( function () {
         getStudents("corsoAB");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line or out function from this sub:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
```

then change source :

```
 $('#buttonAB').click(getStudents("corsoAB"));

   function getStudents(view) {

    /* do something */
   }
```

Comment: I did not need this function.you can don't use it.